# Python regular expression (is it possible to shorten it?)

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to parse the input file which has thousands of lines of text in the form

```
[month/day/year hh:mm:ss AM/PM] FirstName1 LastName1: text.... 

[month/day/year hh:mm:ss AM/PM] FirstName2 LastName2: text....
```

I need to remove text between the brackets, `FirstName` and `LastName`, and leave only the `text` part. I did it the brute force way, but I am sure there is a more elegant way:

```
with open('inputfile.txt') as fin, open('file-out.txt','w') as fout:
    for line in fin:
        fout.write(re.sub('(\[[^)]*\])+(\sFirstName1 LastName1|\sFirstName2 LastName2)', '',line))
```

Is there a way to shorten this regexp (such as use only first 2 letters of the name and last 2 letters of last name or something else?). I haven't used regular expressions a lot, so any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As an alternative to regex, you can split the string on the first occurence of `:` + space.

```
text = line.split(": ", 1)[1]
```

Comment: +1 Or in the same vein: `re.sub(r'.+: ', '', line)`. The real question is whether the OP's data is more complicated than we've been shown. If so, these simple approaches might be too crude.

Comment: Thanks. But if that's all the op needs, this would be sufficient :)

Comment: re.sub(r'.+: ', '', line) returns an empty file. I am trying to process a chat log and analyze the text with nltk later, but I want to remove the date, time and names of chat participants.

Comment: @Anastasia What about my too simple method?

Comment: Yes, that worked! I actually wanted to see a regexp solution as well, but that worked perfectly! Thanks!

Comment: I am sorry, @FMc, your code also worked fine! I mush have made an error when I pasted it into my code!

Answer (score 2):

If you can assume that the first name and the last name don't have any spaces you can just do

`''.join(line.split(' ')[5:])`

Comment: This one returns all strings after :, but they are all merged together, which is not what I need. I need this text for further analysis with nltk, so I need to have the actual word list preserved.

Comment: Ah you didn't say you wanted it in an array, then just use `line.split(' ')[5:]`. Unlike alKid's solution this will work even if there is a ': ' in the text you want to process.